# how can i create custom two options ' referred form and prescribed form' under option menu in odoo 10?

Tags: xml, view, odoo

I am unable to create more options (referred form and prescribed form) options, on which these options opens a new wizard to insert data. Only option appears but second one not appearing and showing error

ParseError: "null value in column "projection" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9749, 2017-07-24 09:45:14.276244, 2017-07-24 09:45:14.276244, 1, null, null, null, 10, form, null, 1, null, t, null, Prescription and Referral Form, primary, prescribed.and.referred.wizard, null, null, null, null).
" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/my_module/wizard/prescribed_and_referred_wizard.xml:3, near

```
 <odoo>
    <record id="view_student_prescription_and_referred" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Prescription and Referral Form</field>
        <field name="model">prescribed.and.referred.wizard</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="10" />
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Prescription and Referral Form">
                <sheet>
                    <header>
                        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                            <img src="/my_module/static/img/obhv.png" />
                        </xpath>
                    </header>
                    <br/>
                    <group colspan="4">
                        <field name="prescribed_and_referred_to" />
                    </group>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="prescribed_and_refer_to" string="Save" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                        <button string="Cancel" special="cancel" class="btn-default"/>
                    </footer>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <act_window 
        name="Prescription and Referral Form"
        id="action_patient_prescription_and_referred"
        src_model="student.visits"
        res_model="prescribed.and.referred.wizard"
        target="new"
        context="{'visit_id': active_id}"
        key2="client_action_multi"
        />
</odoo>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question with full error description?

Comment: Can you guide me if any error or mistake in given above code ?

Comment: ParseError: "null value in column "projection" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (9749, 2017-07-24 09:45:14.276244, 2017-07-24 09:45:14.276244, 1, null, null, null, 10, form, null, 1, null, t, null, Prescription and Referral Form, primary, prescribed.and.referred.wizard, null, null, null, null). " while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/my_module/wizard/prescribed_and_referred_wizard.xml:3, near